# Can I display a form on top of or beside the Windows Vista Login screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication

I have a need to display alerts and such on-screen at any time the computer is running. We have a service running collecting these events, so that's not a problem - but I need to find a way to display critical alerts, even if the user hasn't logged in yet; that is, they're sitting at the 'Press Ctrl-Alt-Delete to log in' prompt.

Is this possible? If so, can it be done via managed code (C#)?

Comment: If the alerts really are that critical, why are you displaying them on the screen of a computer that people are going to be logging out of?  Instead, make a specialized hardware device (or else, a specialized computer with auto-logon) and use that.  On the other hand, if you want to install this on arbitrary desktops, why are the alerts so critical that unauthorized users should be allowed to see them?

Comment: And no, there is no possible way to do this from managed code.  Even doing it from unmanaged C++ is a hack at best and should probably be avoided.

Comment: To answer your question: I know it's really, really stupid. This is what happens when non-technical managers start trying to make technical decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows XP and earlier, the system you'd be working with is GINA. This changed in Vista and Windows 7 to "Credential Providers". See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) for some background.

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing.  Even so, that mechanism is intended for use with alternative authentication providers -- it's not supposed to be used to put user-level notifications on the logon desktop.

Comment: Agreed, but you'd still have to implement that mechanism to affect the logon desktop at all, AFAIK.

Comment: This is about what I figured - but it's for work, and I needed confirmation that it wouldn't be a quickie...